# Можно ли параметризовать target?

Tags: ant

Суть проблемы в том, что написан target, который делает определенный этап в сборке проекта. Теперь мне нужно еще три таких же, но с разным параметром. Наверное, непонятно. Попробую привести простой пример. Допустим, есть target по переименованию:

```
  <target name="replacement">
      <replaceregexp file="${some.file}"
         match='name="test(.*)"'
         replace='name="renamed(.*)"'
       />
  </target>
```

А теперь требуется, чтобы он мог подставлять не только слово "renamed", но и допустим "changed", "edited". Было бы удобно, если бы это можно как-то представить в виде параметра.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, вы не можете описать параметр в описании самого таржета, но вы можете указать параметры при вызове через antcall.

```
<project name="hello">

    <target name="replacement">
            <replaceregexp file="${some.file}" 
                    match='name="test(.*)"'
                    replace='name="${pattern}(.*)"' />
    </target>

    <target name="hello">
            <antcall target="replacement">
                    <param name="pattern" value="renamed" />
            </antcall>

    </target>
</project>
```